# Как мне возвращать из функции одновременно *ptr(измененное значение переменной) и i (условие для кол-ва итераций цикла)

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

Исходная задача:
Для любого числа записать его в двоичной системе счисления и посчитать максимальное кол-во подряд идущих единиц.

Моя проблема:
Мне нужно, чтобы при вызове рекурсии, каждое выполнение функции увеличивало `i` на один и меняло значение `count1` или `count2` по указателю `*ptr` соответственно.
Знаю, что можно передавать значение по адресу, чтобы менять исходную переменную, но не получается здесь это реализовать, так как нужно при выполнении определенных условий менять *ведущую* переменную, то есть адрес не постоянный, `count1` и `count2` меняются и работаю с ними через `*ptr`, а как передавать адрес по значению указателя... в общем я уже тут запутался
Думал через `pair< , >` реализовать, но тогда не понятно, как отдельно с переменными потом работать
Сейчас у меня увеличенное значение `i` не возвращается из функции

Значимая для вопроса часть кода - **начала тела цикла while** и **функция int counter**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int counter(int array[32], int i, int* ptr);

int main()
{
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    int mask = 1;
    int array[32];
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
        if ((a & mask) == mask) {
            array[32 - 1 - i] = 1;
        }
        else array[32 - i - 1] = 0;
        mask = mask << 1;
    }
    int count = 0;
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    int* ptr = &count1;

    int check = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 32) {
        if (array[i] == 1) {
            i++;
            (*ptr)++;
            *ptr = counter(array, i, ptr);
        }
        else {
            check++;
            if (check % 2 != 0) {
                ptr = &count2;
            }
            else {
                count1 = 0;
                count2 = 0;
                ptr = &count1;
            }
            i++;
        }
        // присваиваю значение count в 
        // зависимости от полученных count1 и count2 
        // if{...}
        // if else{...}
        //else{...}
    }
    cout << count;
    return 0;
}


int counter(int array[32], int i, int* ptr) {
    if (array[i] == 1) {
        (*ptr)++;
        i++;
        counter(array, i, ptr);
    }
    return *ptr;
}
```

Comment: Очень сильное ощущение [XY-проблемы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/195342). Лучше опишите свою *исходную* задачу...

Comment: Исходная задача: 
Для любого числа записать его в двоичной системе счисления и посчитать максимальное кол-во подряд идущих единиц. 
Добавил к вопросу.

Comment: Можно возвращать структуру, содержащую нужную вам пару чисел

Comment: Ну для решения исходной задачи вам не нужны ни массивы, ни рекурсия. Просто проверяйте младший бит и сдвигайте число вправо

Comment: Оба метода сработали, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Навскидку на коленке...

```
int count(unsigned long long N)
{
    int cnt = 0, maxcnt = 0;
    for(;N;N>>=1)
    {
        if (N&1) ++cnt;
        else
        {
            if (cnt > maxcnt) maxcnt = cnt;
            cnt = 0;
        }
    }
    if (cnt > maxcnt) maxcnt = cnt;
    return maxcnt;
}
```